# Override set part of a property from base abstract class in the subclass C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, overriding, abstract-class

I have an abstract class called `A` that is the base class for another class called `B`. I want to override the `DrawingType` property in `B`. Here is my code:

```
public abstract class A
{
    protected DrawingType m_type;

    public DrawingType Type
    {
        get { return m_type; }
        set { m_type = value}
    }
}

public B : A
{
    // I want to override the 'set' of DrawingType property here.
}
```

How can I override the `DrawingType` property in `B`?

Comment: 1) Your `A` class doesn't look very abstract from its declaration, 2) The property is `Type`, not `DrawingType`, 3) Mark the `Type` property as `virtual` so you can override it. You'll need to override both get and set. You can't just pick one of them.

Comment: Alternatively to @itsme86's suggestion, you could also create a virtual method and mark the properties setter as private, then only do the setting through the virtual method which you would override from the sub-class, just an alternative, prefer the first solution...

Comment: @CodexNZ Thanks, actually that is the way I'm doing it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes should look like the following:

```
abstract class A
{
    protected DrawingType m_type;

    protected virtual DrawingType Type
    {
        get { return m_type; }
        set { m_type = value; }
    }
}

class B : A
{
    protected override DrawingType Type
    {
        get
        {
            return m_type;
        }
        set
        {
            m_type = //custom logic goes here
        }
    }
}
```

If the base class doesn't have an implementation you can use

```
abstract class A
{
    protected DrawingType m_type;

    protected abstract DrawingType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No, the property in class `A` should be `virtual`, not `abstract`. You can't have an `abstract` class member with an implementation.